# react-native call onSubmit() when pressed returnKeyType

Tags: react-native, keyboard, onsubmit

I'm new to react-native.

I'm struggling on keyboard now. I have TextInput and a button. What I want is that, when user entered input through keyboard, he/she can go to next page with just one click on the return button. So what I simply want is that onSubmit method should be called when user clicks "return" button on keyboard.
Is there anyone can help me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `onSubmitEditing` callback of `TextInput`

Example.

```
<TextInput
   onSubmitEditing={(event) => this.onSubmitHandler(event)}
/>
```

You can get more information from [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html)