# How to submit redux form in React Native by pressing Enter key on virtual keyboard?

Tags: forms, react-native, redux

I have a question regarding virtual keyaboard and submitting a form on Android.
I have a react-redux form and I want it to submit when user hits Enter key after typing. But virtual keyboard has only such button

**(with tick icon)**

[image]

after hitting which keyboard just hides and no submit. In some apps I saw such button

**(with arrow button)**

[image]

after pressing which submit event occurs. In web form Enter key submits form by default, but in mobile not. What do I have to do to make virtual keyboard have such "submit" button, instead of 'OK' button?

Here is the code:

```
class SearchBenefitsForm extends React.Component<IProps> {
 renderTextInput = ({ input, autoFocus }: { input: any, autoFocus: boolean }) => {
 return (
   <TextInput
     {...input}
     autoFocus={autoFocus}
     underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
   />
 );
 }

 render() {
 const {
   handleSubmit,
   submitting,
   invalid,
   onCancel,
 } = this.props;

 return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleSubmit} disabled={submitting || invalid}>
       <Image style={styles.searchIcon} source={searchIcon}/>
     </TouchableOpacity>
     <View style={styles.searchExpression}>
       <Field
         name={SEARCH_BENEFITS_EXPRESSION}
         autoFocus={true}
         component={this.renderTextInput}
       />
     </View>
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={onCancel} disabled={submitting || invalid}>
       <Image style={styles.closeIcon} source={closeIcon}/>
     </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
     );
   }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: SEARCH_BENEFITS_FORM,
})(SearchBenefitsForm);
```

Comment: Please import your images and format your sourcecode!

Comment: try with `onSubmitEditing` property of `TextInput`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have not set keyboardType in your Textinput Props. The second Screenshot looks like keyboardType="email".
[More information here.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#keyboardtype)

Your TextInput should look like this:

```
<TextInput
    value="..."
    keyboardType="email"
/>
```

Comment: The keyboard changes when I set different keyboardType, but the bottom right button stays the same (like a tick button). And I want the form to trigger submit event when user presses the this Enter button.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421222/react-native-call-onsubmit-when-pressed-returnkeytype this should be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice, onSubmitEditing is the right solution for this question.

Here is the code:

```
class SearchBenefitsForm extends React.Component<IProps> {
 renderTextInput = ({ input, autoFocus, onSubmitEditing }: { input: any,
                  autoFocus: boolean, onSubmitEditing: Function }) => 
 {
 return (
   <TextInput
     {...input}
     autoFocus={autoFocus}
     underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
     onSubmitEditing={onSubmitEditing}
   />
 );
 }

 render() {
 const {
   handleSubmit,
   submitting,
   invalid,
   onCancel,
 } = this.props;

 return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleSubmit} disabled={submitting || invalid}>
       <Image style={styles.searchIcon} source={searchIcon}/>
     </TouchableOpacity>
     <View style={styles.searchExpression}>
       <Field
         name={SEARCH_BENEFITS_EXPRESSION}
         autoFocus={true}
         component={this.renderTextInput}
         onSubmitEditing={handleSubmit}
       />
     </View>
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={onCancel} disabled={submitting || invalid}>
       <Image style={styles.closeIcon} source={closeIcon}/>
     </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
     );
   }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: SEARCH_BENEFITS_FORM,
})(SearchBenefitsForm);
```